# Convergence of Riemann sums with partitions with equidistant points

Tags: riemann-integration, riemann-sum

I am reading Spivak's book "Calculus".
The definition of integrable given there is the following:
[image]

$L(f,P)$ and $U(f,P)$ are the lower sum and the upper sum of $f$ for partition $P$.

I understand that it is a classic definition of integrable function but not the only one. For example, another definition is given in this question:
[Riemann sums with equidistant sample points converge to the integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1008626/riemann-sums-with-equidistant-sample-points-converge-to-the-integral)

In the same book I mentioned before I found the following exercise:

[image]

Part a) has not been a problem. However, I cannot build the example requested in part b).

Could you give me any suggestion to solve this problem. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Exercise 12(b) looks like a mistake to me.  Is it in the most recent edition of the textbook?  I can't find this exercise in the Third Edition, where in Chapter 13, he does use Theorem 1 of the Appendix to Chapter 8 (as mentioned in your "Exercise 12(a)") to prove that continuous functions on closed intervals are Riemann integrable.  But Spivak's Third Edition does this in the main text (in what he labels as "Theorem 3"), not in the exercises, and Exercise 12 of Chapter 13 in the Third Edition is something else.

Answer (score 2):

I find the following result in the book Real Analysis by Claude Warnick. The definition of integrable given there is similar to the one given in Spivak's book. So, I think there is something wrong in the statement of exercise b.

[image]

Comment: Okay, indeed. Sorry for misleading you for so long, I really should've thought about your problem for a while before writing anything. Let $\epsilon > 0$. Now for all $n$ such that $\frac{1}{n}<\delta$ we have $\int_a^b f \ge L(f, P_n)$ or $-\int_a^b f \le -L(f, P_n)$. Thus we get $U(f, P_n)-\int_a^b f \le U(f, P_n)-L(f, P_n) < \epsilon$. Therefore, you are correct,  the answer to the question is "does not exist" and I apologize

Comment: There's no need to apologize. The discussion was helpful.